# Finding a ratio of two triple integrals with different limits

Tags: calculus, integration

I was doing a problem and came to a step where i did not know how to continue. I have to show that ratio of two integrals is equal to 2.
$$I_1 = \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{dx dy dz}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}$$
$$I_2 = \int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2} \frac{dx dy dz}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}$$
So i have to show that $\frac{I_1}{I_2}=2$ without solving those integrals. I have to manipulate variables and limits somehow.

Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Try the substitutions $x'=x/2,y'=y/2$ and $z'=z/2$ within $I_2$ in order to change the borders to $0$ and $1$.

Now note that the integrand is an even function and therefore you can apply

$$\int_0^af(x)dx=\frac12\int_{-a}^af(x)dx$$

Can you take it from hereon?

Comment: Thanks!! That substitution worked wonders. The rest was easy.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help :)